# How to structure a Azure Table to hold user messages

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm still trying to get my head around the correct way to use Azure Tables.  I understand that they have a partition key and a row key, that that's it.  Everything else is just data that you keep in that row.

**Use Case**
My web app gets files uploaded by a user, puts them in a queue, then has a worker roll process the queue and do analytics on those files.

I would like to put messages about those files in an Azure Table based on what we find when we process those files.

I then plan on making an AJAX call to get a members messages when they visit a webpage.  If the user clicks on the message or closes the message then I'll delete it from the table. Very StackOverflowish.

**Question**
My question is on how to best store these messages in my Azure Table.

Here's my thinking so far:

**PartionKey**: MemberID
**RowKey**: ???(not sure what to have)
**Column Data**: Message data including any links and a time stamp.  Probably a view count too.

I can't think of what I would put in a seperate index for the row key.  Timestamp could work so I can order messages correctly, but I don't think I'll get much bang for my buck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that the best to think about the choice of partition and row keys is to think about the data access patterns. If your access pattern is to have a single row/entity represent something meaningful in your system. In your case is sounds like userid/fileid uniquely identifies the entity. From this, you have three options:

1. userid for partition key, fileid for row key
2. constant value for partition key, and a combination of userid and fileid for row key
3. constant value for row key, and a combination of userid and fileid for partition key

The decision on there is to figure out what other access pattern. Are you going to be querying for all files for a particular user? Then you would want userid as partition or row key. If you will only ever be querying based on fileid/userid, then it doesn't really matter.

Erick

Answer (score 0):

Before thinking about actual storage, you should try to think about what entities you're going to have.
Sounds like something like this:

User entity
UserFile entity
FileMessage entity

Do you have one FileMessage per UserFile or can you have more than one?  It sounds like (by your explanation of deletion logic) that you would only have one FileMessage per File.

If my assumptions so far are correct and if it were me, the FileMessage table would have the following structure:
PartitionKey: userId
RowKey: fileId (name/url/etc)
Other columns: as you see fit

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I would think of it as: Partition Key is how you want to break data out, so if data is related, you want to keep the partition key the same.  If you are doing something with a lot of data, you may want to use like the date for the Partition Key.  The Row Key is the index, so that is what you will use to query the data.